# Live SDK Error in registering new application?

Tags: c#, msn

I am trying to Create a new application to get contacts from msn.
First of all I created my application in live SDK everything is ok except the redirect uri, each time I am trying to add it as http://localhost:3225 that gives me an error

> You must enter a valid domain that begins with http:// or https:// -
>   query strings are not allowed. Length is limited to 248 characters.

And I need to work local for now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Run notepad with admin permission
2. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
3. Select show everything instead of `*.txt`
4. Open Hosts
5. Add a fake domain like for example:`[127.0.0.1       Local201406031703.com]`
6. now you can use `http://Local201406031703.com:3225` instead of `localhost:3225.`